# Minimum value of $\dfrac{a+b+c}{b-a}$

Tags: calculus

> $f(x)= ax^2 +bx +c ~ ~~(a<b)$ and $f(x)\ge 0~ \forall x \in \mathbb R$ .
>   Find the minimum value of $\dfrac{a+b+c}{b-a}$

Attempt:

$b^2 \le 4ac$

$f(1) = a+b+c$

$f(0) = c$

$f(-1) = a-b+c$

$a>0$
and $c>0$

I am unable to utilize these things to find the minimum value of the expression $\equiv \dfrac{a+b+\frac {b^2}{4a}}{b-a}$

The answer given is $3$.

Comment: $c=0,\ b=\infty,\ a=-\infty$ where $\infty$ represents large numbers. When you sub in $\infty$, you get $\frac0{2\infty}$, which basically equals $0$.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley but $a\ge 0$, otherwise $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, you are on the right track! Now let's complete it with only elementary calculus.

$$\frac{a+b+\frac{b^2}{4a}}{b-a}=\frac{4a^2+4ab+b^2}{4a(b-a)}=\frac{(2a+b)^2}{4a(b-a)}$$

Knowing that $b>a$, let's set $b=ka, k>1$.
$$\frac{(2a+b)^2}{4a(b-a)}=\frac{(2+k)^2a^2}{4(k-1)a^2}=\frac{(2+k)^2}{4(k-1)}$$

Now you just need to find the minimum of this function for $k>1$. You can differentiate it and check that $k=4$ is a critical point, and you get $\frac{a+b+c}{b-a}=3$ there as a minimum.

Answer (score 9):

Alt. hint: $\;f(-2) = 4a - 2 b + c \ge 0 \iff 2a + c \ge 2(b-a)\,$, then:

$$
\dfrac{a+b+c}{b-a} = 1 + \frac{2a+c}{b-a} \;\ge\; 1 + 2 = 3
$$

Comment: What a fine trick!

Comment: Nice answer! Is there any motivation behind plugging in $x=-2$, or do you just try some small integer values of $x$ and see what crops up?

Comment: @Macrophage Thank you. This still leaves the OP with proving that the lower bound is in fact attained, but given the tone of the question I guess this won't be a problem.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Thanks. It started with breaking a $\,b-a\,$ off the fraction, then trying to relate $\,(2a+c)\,$ and $\,\lambda (b-a)\,$ back to the quadratic somehow. I reckon this was a lucky shot, and/or this was meant to be a trick problem since the solution requires *a lot* less than the given assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the equation as $x^2+Bx+C$. Now, $B^2\le 4C$ So, the minimum value of $C=\dfrac{B^2}{4}$. Now, $\dfrac {a+b+c}{b−a} =\dfrac {1+B+(B^2/4)}{B−1}$. Find the minimum value of function.